# XSLT: flatten tree

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to convert Kodi-compatible xml to Xtreamer-compatible xml.
The input looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>something</id>
  <title>something</title>
  <originaltitle>something</originaltitle>
...and so on... several unknown nodes
  <actor>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <role>Role1</role>
    <order>0</order>
  </actor>
  <actor>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <role>Role2</role>
    <order>1</order>
  </actor>
  <actor>
    <name>Name3</name>
    <role>Role3</role>
    <order>2</order>
  </actor>
...several other unknown nodes...
</movie>
```

What I'd like to have is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movie xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <id>something</id>
  <title>something</title>
  <originaltitle>something</originaltitle>
...and so on... several unknown nodes
  <actor>
    <name>Name1</name>
    <name>Name2</name>
    <name>Name3</name>
  </actor>
...several other unknown nodes...
</movie>
```

...so just drop every child item of actor besides name and put all the names into one common actor tag. The rest of the document should stay unchanged.

What I tried is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
 <xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/movie">
 <actor>
 <xsl:for-each select="actor">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </actor>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What I get is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<actor xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><name xmlns="">Name1</name><name xmlns="">Name2</name><name xmlns="">Name3</name></actor>
<id>something</id>
<title>something</title>
<originaltitle>something</originaltitle>
...and so on... several unknown nodes
<actor>
<name>Name1</name>
<role>Role1</role>
<order>0</order>
</actor>
<actor>
<name>Name2</name>
<role>Role2</role>
<order>1</order>
</actor>
<actor>
<name>Name3</name>
<role>Role3</role>
<order>2</order>
</actor>
...several other unknown nodes...
```

Some things don't work work like wanted:

1. All the actor-nodes and their children are still in the output.
2. The
   actor-name-name-name-actor-Block:

   - replaces the movie-tag
   - is in the beginning, not at the position, where the actor-nodes used to be before
   - has no line breaks

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "*The rest of the document should stay unchanged.*" Are you sure about that? I notice that your stylesheet has a default namespace  "`http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"`. If that's something you really need your output to have, then you will have to change the namespace of **all** the transformed elements - which means you cannot use cannot use `xsl:copy` at all.

Comment: Sorry, no, that was a mistake. I deleted this attribute now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
 <xsl:copy>
 <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="actor[1]">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:copy-of select="../actor/name" />
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="actor" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Instead of using the movie element, I transform the actors. This prevents the movie tag from disappearing, and it will keep the actors in place.

There are two rules for actor, Only the first element will actually select all the names. The other will just remain blank.

The line breaks are still not correct though. But I think it's a bit weird you are so focused on line breaks, as they do not matter in XML. But perhaps you want it so it is more readable.

Comment: Thank You. Very good. This was I was thinking of all the time, but didn't find the way to select all actor-tags together, not seperately. This solves my main problem. The remaining thing of the missing line breaks ist not so important.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your template ;

```
<xsl:template match="/movie">
 <actor>
 <xsl:for-each select="actor">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="name"/>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </actor>
 <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
```

is that:

1. it does not copy the matched `movie` node; and
2. it applies templates indiscriminately - including to the `actor`
   children which are also handled separately.

What you should have done is:

```
<xsl:template match="/movie">
    <xsl:copy>
        <actor>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="actor/name"/>
         </actor>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::actor)]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if you really must maintain the position of `actor` among its siblings (why is this important?):

```
<xsl:template match="/movie">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="actor[1]/preceding-sibling::*"/>       
        <actor>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="actor/name"/>
         </actor>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="actor[last()]/following-sibling::*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

> • has no line breaks

I cannot reproduce this problem using your code, but you should have these two at the top level of your stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

**NOTE:**

As I already mentioned in my comment on your question, this assumes the output XML does **NOT** need to place its nodes in a namespace - otherwise there's a lot more work that needs to be done.

Comment: Thanks for Your help, too. This last snippet also solves my line breaks problem. I wanted to have the line breaks and the original position for pure readability.